# Изменение полей класса

Tags: python, python-3.x, классы

У меня есть класс `Element`, который содержит в себе некоторую информацию. Так же есть класс `ArrayrEl`, который содержит массив элементов класса `Element`.

Пусть у `ArrayEl` есть метод `to_change`, который возвращает генератор/список объектов класса `Element` из массива `ArrayEl`, которые нужно изменить (тут важно не возвращать индексы, у меня могут быть другие поля в `ArrayEl`, которые не находятся в массиве, но могут быть возвращены).

И есть у `ArrayEl` другой метод `change`, который должен присваивать `None` некоторым элементам из полей `ArrayEl`. Собственно эти объекты `to_change` и должен возвращать.

Пример кода:

```py
class Element:

    def __init__(self, is_change):
        self.strnum = '8' if is_change else '6'
        self.is_change = is_change

    def __repr__(self):
        return str((self.strnum, self.is_change))

class ArrayEl:
    def __init__(self):
        self.array = [Element(False), Element(True)]
        self.other = Element(True)

    def __repr__(self):
        return str((self.other, self.array))

    def to_change(self):
        if self.other.is_change:
            yield self.other
        for el in self.array:
            if el.is_change:
                yield el

    def change(self):
        for el in self.to_change():
            el = None


m = ArrayEl()
m.change()
print(m)
# Реальный вывод: (('8', True), [('6', False), ('8', True)])
# Ожидаемый вывод: (None, [('6', False), None])
```

Получается, что `el = None` не изменяет объект по ссылке. Как это исправить?

Comment: Значения элементов в `array` в общем случае уникальны?

Comment: @V-Mor К сожалению, нет

Comment: @Илиан, а можете пояснить, по какого рода причине нельзя возвращать индесы? К примеру, некая параллельность, из-за которой индекс может стать неверным, пока дойдёт до изменения, или причины не связаны с изменением индесов во времени? Во втором случае, насколько могу судить, в Вашем методе `change(self)` при итерации `for el in self.to_change():` можно брать `id(el)`, находить в `self.array` элемент с таким же `id` и его (этот элемент) устанавливать в `None` - это допустимый вариант или нет?

Comment: В принципе, поиск по `id` - просто следствие того, что значения элементов не уникальны, как у Вас спрашивали, т.е. это по сути замена метода `index`

Comment: @EurobeatIntensifies, у меня помимо массива может изменяться поле `self.other`, а значит при использовании такого способо придётся отдельно разбирать такой случай. А я добавил функцию `to_change` в целях упрощения кода (просто у меня много различных `change`).  А если разбирать случай, то код проще не становится.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вы не можете просто подменить один объект другим через присваивание.

Присваивание объекта некоторой переменной делает так, что переменная начинает указывать на новый объект. Но это не влияет на другие переменные, которые на него указывали и на контейнеры, в которых старый объект содержится.

Нужно менять всю логику.

Самое простое - хранить в элементе информацию о том, что он удалён:

```
class Element:

    def __init__(self, is_change):
        self.strnum = '8' if is_change else '6'
        self.is_change = is_change
        self.valid = True  # Добавил

    def __repr__(self):
        return str((self.strnum, self.is_change) if self.valid else None)  # Изменил


class ArrayEl:

    def __init__(self):
        self.array = [Element(False), Element(True)]
        self.other = Element(True)

    def __repr__(self):
        return str((self.other, self.array))

    def to_change(self):
        if self.other.is_change:
            yield self.other
        for el in self.array:
            if el.is_change:
                yield el

    def change(self):
        for el in self.to_change():
            el.valid = False    # Изменил
```

Либо менять всю логику изменения элементов, отдельно разбирая `other`, и отдельно `array`.

Либо можно хранить один общий пул элементов и как-то разметить его, чтобы было понятно, какие из них относятся к `array`, а какие к `other`.

Тогда можно нормально работать по индексам:

```
class Element:

    def __init__(self, is_change):
        self.strnum = '8' if is_change else '6'
        self.is_change = is_change

    def __repr__(self):
        return str((self.strnum, self.is_change))


class ArrayEl:

    def __init__(self):
        array = [Element(False), Element(True)]
        other = Element(True)
        self.elements = [other, *array]

    @property
    def other(self):
        return self.elements[0]

    @property
    def array(self):
        return self.elements[1:]

    def __repr__(self):
        return str((self.other, self.array))

    def to_change(self):
        for idx, el in enumerate(self.elements):
            if el.is_change:
                yield idx

    def change(self):
        for idx in self.to_change():
            self.elements[idx] = None
```

Answer (score 1):

Есть ещё вариант оставить `other` и `array` в текущем виде и без содания обёртки над ними. В классах есть словарь `__dict__`, который хранит атрибуты этого класса (в случае создания объекта класса `ArrayEl` этот словарь выглядит как `{'array': [('6', False), ('8', True)], 'other': ('8', True)}`). Так вот, я предлагаю возвращать пути в этом словаре при помощи метода `paths_to_change` (который выступает заменой имеющегося метода `to_change`). Ну а менять собственно значения словаря `__dict__` по этим путям. Изменения кода такие:

```
from functools import reduce


class ArrayEl:
    ...
    # новый метод
    def paths_to_change(self):
        if self.other.is_change:
            yield ['other']
        for idx, el in enumerate(self.array):
            if el.is_change:
                yield ['array', idx]

    # изменённый Ваш метод
    def change(self):
        for idcs in self.paths_to_change():
            reduce(dict.__getitem__, idcs[:-1], self.__dict__)[idcs[-1]] = None

    ...
```

Конструкция `reduce(dict.__getitem__, idcs[:-1], self.__dict__)[idcs[-1]]` нужно для того, чтоб единообразно изменять как `other` (доступ к нему осуществляется по ключу, состоящему из одой строки, т.е. длина `idcs` здесь 1), так и элементы `array` (для доступа нужен ещё и индекс элемента в этом списке, т.е. длина `idcs` здесь 2).

Проверка:

```
m = ArrayEl()
print(m)    # ('8', True) [('6', False), ('8', True)]
m.change()
print(m)    # None [('6', False), None]
```